Having trouble setting up Maven on MAC OS
I have been trying for the past week to set up maven on my MacBook Pro. I have looked through this forum and tried different solutions however I am still stuck and that is why I am compelled to post for help. I am learning java on my own as a hobby and I would really appreciate any feed back or help. Thank you!
export M2_HOME=/Users/mycomputer/projects/tools/apache-maven-3.9.6
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=$M2_HOME/bin:$M2_HOME/bin:$PATH
I then used this line in the terminal to check.

mvn -version

And the response is

The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly,
this environment variable is needed to run this program.
mycomputer@Mys-MacBook-Pro ~ %

Maven Version:

/Users/mycomputer/projects/tools/apache-maven-3.9.6/bin/mvn
mycomputer@Mys-MacBook-Pro ~ %

JDK Version:

java version "11.0.22" 2024-01-16 LTS

I tried redownloading maven and jdk to my system. I have tried different commands in the terminal.

Try sdkman. And why use an obsolete version of java?

https://sdkman.io/ also https://brew.sh/
